# I want to run my algo game via fulfillRandomWords is VRF2 Chainlink

Tags: solidity, vrf, chainlink-vrf

```
function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomness)
        internal
        override
    {
//_requestIdToGameId already has gameId, a function who requests randomness, set it
        uint256 gameId = _requestIdToGameId[requestId];
        runAlgo(gameId, randomResult);
        emit RequestRandomnessFulfilledRunGame(requestId, randomness[0]);
    }
```

RunAlgo works fine. When I added safeTransferFrom in the loop inside runAlgo, it has crashed, again and again.

runAlgo works fine, when I called it directly, I can see the main logic done, and tokens transferred via algo in a loop.
However, when I call it via Vrf callback fulfillRandomWords  - it's crashed:(
I have few suggestions, would be great if anyone can provide more details here for me.

So I think, that fulfillRandomWords has gas limit, follow VRF2 docs it's 2500000
When I called requestRandom directly -> callback called by VRF fulfillRandomWords -> calls runAlgo.  I'm probably out of gas.
Is it right? or do I have a misunderstanding here?

I pretty sure that I have no code errors. All functions works separately.

Just grabbed gas for my 3 functions if I called them in seperate.

920,454(RunAlgo) +  125,022(RequestRandomnessFulfilledRunAlgo) +  760,100(RandomWordsRequested) so it's < 2500000 what is my gasLimit, for example in ethereum or polygon chains.

Comment: I don't agree with the answer, I have enough gas to cover the transaction. 
It's less than my limit 2.5 million